# Use existing MDF Database on WindowsPhone 8.1

Tags: entity-framework, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, mdf

Is it possible to use an existing `.MDF` database file on a Windows Phone with Entity Framework?

Or what are the steps to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.mdf` database files are handled by Microsoft **SQL Server** - and there is **no version** of SQL Server (the full, server-based version) available on the Windows Phone platform.

The only way to make this possible is to put the SQL Server database on a server and provide some e.g. service-style interface (REST service or something) that the Windows Phone app can consume.

The other option would be to extract the relevant info from the SQL Server database into a database format like SQLite or SQL Server **Compact Edition** (`.sdf` files) that are supported on Windows Phone - but then you have to consider how to keep those two platforms (SQL Server on the server, SQLite / SQL Server CE on the phone) in sync.